# Sql server's Constant scan - clarification?

Tags: sql-server

I've read [*this article about*](http://www.scarydba.com/2008/07/01/constant-scan-in-execution-plans/) Constant scan but still didn't understand when it would be used ( *people commented the author that his article still isn't understood*):

MSDN :

> The Constant Scan operator introduces one or more constant rows into a
>   query. A Compute Scalar operator is often used to add columns to a row
>   produced by a Constant Scan operator.

very unclear.

For example :

why does `SELECT TOP 1  GETDATE()` produces :

[image]

While `select getdate()` produces nothing. ( in execution plan).

I guess it has to do with constant scan. so :

**Question :**

- What exactly is constant scan
- Why do it needs to SCAN something  if it's a constant  , and
- Why does `select top 1 getdate()` yield different result than plain `select getdate()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because *most* of the operators that are used in fulfilling a query are specified in terms of one or more input rowsets and one or more output rowsets, it makes sense that if you write a query that requires the use of one of those operators, you'd better make sure that the input that you present to that operator is a rowset.

So the constant scan operator is a special operator that can take one or more scalar inputs and generate a rowset.

It makes composing operators far easier.

---

> Why does `select top 1 getdate()` yield different result than plain `select getdate()`

Because you've asked to use the `TOP` operator. And the `TOP` operator expects to have an input rowset.

---

To why I think focussing on the performance is irrelevant:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
GO
SELECT TOP 1  GETDATE()
GO
SELECT GETDATE()
```

Messages:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(1 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(1 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

That is, we can't even get a measure of the amount of time that either statement takes to execute.

Comment: Damien , what it actually scans ? top of what ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - it doesn't actually perform any scanning. But its name is consistent with (some) other operators that also can generate rowsets.

Comment: In a matter of micro performance , is there ANY difference ? (vs `select getdate()`)

Comment: @RoyiNamir - I wouldn't even bother measuring it. If that is truly, anything close to being on your critical performance path, you're doing lots of other things wrong.

Comment: Im just asking for pure knowledge. nothing beyond

Comment: @RoyiNamir - that's not knowledge, that's trivia.

Comment: Damien , I obviously dont have sql server knowedge as you do , but for me , seeing in execution plan "ConstantScan=85%" and not knowing if it has performance impact  - even the slightest percent - makes me less prefossional sql developer.  not to mention that it's a Q/A site :-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir - I've added a section where I turn on timing and run both statements. Every part of the processing is taking time below that which SQL Server will measure - so its all reported as `0ms`.

Comment: Damien , I jsut checked this `SELECT TOP 1  GETDATE()    FROM  NORTHWND.dbo.Customers` ( 1m rows)  and I got this result http://i.stack.imgur.com/yHnwW.jpg - it does scan the index ,  and still the time is 0. how can it be ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - well, now you've written a query where it does actually have to access the table to obtain at least one row. But still, the amount of time taken is below the measures that SQL Server provides - so again, you wouldn't want to focus efforts on optimization here. If `Customers` contained no rows, this query would now return no results, rather than the current date.