# How to add a value to a pseudo table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a list from a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders.Order ID
```

This returns:

```
OrderID
10255
10267
10275
10278
10298
```

I want to add 11245 to this data, temporarily, not to the original table. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks

Comment: `INSERT INTO Orders.Order (ID) VALUES (11245)`? And then `DELETE FROM Orders.Order WHERE ID = 11245`?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by a Pseudo table here, by the way? Why is `Orders.Order` not a "real" table?

Comment: @larnu By pseudo table I mean a subset of a table. Orders is one field from a bigger table. (this is still related to that INTERSECT dataset i'm working with)

Comment: `Orders`, in the above, is a schema not a column, @Noobcoder . Don't confuse the 2; they are nothing alike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the UNION ALL operator, like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders.Order ID
UNION ALL
SELECT 11245
```

UNION will also work, but in case the new value also exists in the original result set, you will only see that value appearing once in the final result set.

Comment: `UNION ALL` would be more efficient here.

Comment: Right, let me edir

Comment: This is exactly what I was after, thanks! Took me deleting an old question and creating this one before people understood what I was trying to do! :)  Thanks!

Comment: Quick followup question @shree.pat18. What does "SELECT 11245" actually do in SQL? Does it create a table? i.e. is that why it lets you union the two tables together? Just trying to think of what's happening under the hood a bit.

Comment: This may be of interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751868/sql-servers-constant-scan-clarification